# Weird characters when retrieving a JSON with Node.Js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, encoding

Im trying to get a json from an API.
The response has some non english chars so i encode the response with utf-8.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
 next();
});
```

Im getting some wierd characters.

This is how i retrieve the data:

```
var reqObj = http.get( url, function(res) {
    var oj= '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        oj += chunk;
      });

res.on('end', function() {
     console.log(oj);    // output =  '??{"title":  " ????? ????? ????? "}'
     JSON.parse(oj);     // parsing failed - unexpected token ?

 });
```

Why do i get weird chars beore the json and in the json itself if i decode the response in utf-8?
This causes parsing to json to fail.
Any ides for solving this?

**EDIT:**
I set  res.setEncoding('binary');
and got this output:
[image]

Comment: If you read your JSON server side, do you have this problem ? It's maybe a problem of the API (wrong database encoding ?)

Comment: You try to use escape|unescape and decodeURIComponent|encodeURIComponent ?

Comment: @r4ge  no. Im not familiar with these. How are they used ?

Comment: @r4ge Ok, i read about these functions and tried. The output for encodeURIComponent is : %C3%BF%C3%BE.   And for decodeURIComponent a wierd char and an underline char.

Comment: update : now im getting  %EF%BF%DB%EF%BF%BD which means NULL ( itis ok getting null). How can i decode this in node.js to get an empty string??

Comment: How you now it is NULL? Maybe now decodeURIComponent work right?

Comment: @r4ge I know it means null because this site says so :)  http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=EF+BF+DB+EF+BF+BD&mode=obytes

Comment: Setting the `Content-Type` header does not automagically encode your response somehow. You need to show where you are actually sending the JSON response on the server.

Comment: @r4ge I also tried setting the res.setEncoding('utf8); and tried using iconv-lite library. all failed

Comment: @user4440845: Your link: http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=EF+BF+DB+EF+BF+BD&mode=obytes is interpreting hex characters as octal, so since `E` and `F` is not an octal character, I presume it simply replaces it with `0` which is null. Choose the right interpretation (FYI, interpreting 0xEF as unicode code-point on that page gives me `ï`)